# Flying back to Hawaii from Stuttgart Germany - Need Visa?

Tags: transit-visas

Do I need some sort of transit visa returning to Hawaii from Stuttgart, Germany with an 11 hr 50 min layover in London LGW then connecting on to Seattle, WA and on to Lihue, Kauai, Hawaii?

Comment: Depends on what passport you hold and what visas are in that passport. For most travellers, no.

Comment: I'm guessing a US citizen from the "returning to Hawaii", but I'd need clarification.